# PHP Parse XML with Attributes

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document that I am trying to get some of the values for and don't know how to get to the attributes.  An example of the structure and values are below:

```
<vin_number value="3N1AB51D84L729887">

  <common_data>

    <engines>

    </engines>

  </common_data>

  <available_vehicle_styles>

    <vehicle_style name="SE-R 4dr Sedan" style_id="100285116" complete="Y">

      <engines>

        <engine brand="" name="ED 2L NA I 4 double overhead cam (DOHC) 16V"></engine>

      </engines>

    </vehicle_style>

  </available_vehicle_styles>

</vin_number>
```

I am trying to get the engine["name"] attribute (NOT "ENGINES"). I thought the following would work but I get errors (I cant parse past "vehicle_style")

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fileVIN);

foreach($xml->vin_number->available_vehicle_styles->vehicle_style->engines->engine->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $b;
}
```

Comment: You keep saying that you "get errors", knowing the contents of those errors would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* your XML is structured in the same was as [this example XML](https://raw.github.com/gist/2af1c2ca5755d5b8623f/e73b0b5b55591324339e6017852e84890481a4b3/dataone_decoded_win_data.xml), the following two  snippets will get the engine name.

The property hierarchy way (split onto multiple lines so you can read it).

```
$name = (string) $xml->vin_number
                     ->available_vehicle_styles
                     ->vehicle_style
                     ->engines
                     ->engine['name'];
```

Or the more concise XPath way.

```
$engines = $xml->xpath('//engines/engine');
$name = (string) $engines[0]['name'];
```

Unless there are multiple engine names in your XML, there is no need to use a `foreach` loop at all.

<sup>([See both snippets running on a codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7lrmcA).)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method to get the attributes:

```
foreach($xml->available_vehicle_styles->vehicle_style as $b) {
    $attrs = $b->attributes();
    echo "Name = $attrs->name";
}
```

Note: I slightly changed the "path" to the element starting from `$xml` because that's how it loaded the fragment for me.

Comment: I got that, but what i needed to do was to get the attribute names of "engine" so I thought I would do the same as above but I keep getting errors: $xml->available_vehicle_styles->vehicle_style->engines->engine as $b

Answer (score -1):

By this layout, there could be more than one engine per engines block, so you have to explicitly pick the first one. (Assuming you know for sure there's only going to be one.)

```
$name = $xml->available_vehicle_styles->vehicle_style->engines->engine[0]->attributes()->name;
```

Comment: I tried your code above and got errors... if I do the following it prints out fine... ($xml->vin_number->available_vehicle_styles->vehicle_style[0]->attributes()->name) so for engine I tried the following and still got errors ... ($xml->vin_number->available_vehicle_styles->vehicle_style[0]->engines[0]->engine[0]->attributes()->name)

Comment: I have been at this all day and I just emailed the company that I am downloading the XML file from. I edited the structure of the XML data above.  I dont know if there is an error in the file that they sent me but I am trying to get to second engines->engine node. and when the first one is empty I get an error.  Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a node at the top added named "common_data"

Comment: It works totally fine with the XML you originally posted: http://codepad.org/r2Je30qJ

Comment: My post went above this a couple answers.  I think there are artifacts present in the XML file that is being downloaded.